# Excel Hyperlinks that auto filter

Tags: excel, excel-2003

Is there anyway to make a hyperlink such that once clicked from "Sheet1" I will be redirected to "Sheet2" and automatically filtered my data based on the hyperlink range or value.

Or could I use the hyperlink to go to a specific range in another sheet but HIDE everything not in that range?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use a macro, and attach it to a hyperlink

Comment: and how would that look, I don't know anything about macros. Thanks.

Comment: in that case your friend is a pivot table with slicers.  ask for it in superuser.com how to do them, because it won't be related to programming subjects (rules of stackoverflow).  or search for video tutorials on the subject, I'm sure you'll find plenty of them in youtube

Answer (score 2):

To implement attaching a macro to a hyperlink:

Add a Worksheet_FollowHyperlink event handler to the Worksheet,

eg if for a hyperlink on cell E4

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$E$4" Then
        MsgBox "You can run some code if this hyperlink to " & _
            Target.SubAddress & " in " & Target.Range.Address & " is clicked"
    End If
End Sub
```

This executes after the hyperlink is followed, the MsgBox code should be replaced with code to AutoFilter the active sheet, which will be the target sheet, Sheet2 in this case.